# How could higher-order Datalog be more expressive than first-order Datalog?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, logic, logic-programming, datalog

According to [this paper](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/theory-and-practice-of-logic-programming/article/abs/expressive-power-of-higherorder-datalog/B800F077DBC66023631AF4139B9F0B47) [1], higher-order Datalog is more expressive:

> ... we demonstrate that on ordered databases, for all `k ≥ 2`,
> `k`-order Datalog captures `(k − 1)-EXPTIME`. This result suggests that higher-order extensions of Datalog possess superior expressive power ...

But how is it possible for higher-order Datalog to be more expressive?

Can't we simply take every statement like

```
a(X, Y) :- b(X, Y, Z), a(Y, Z).
```

and rewrite it as:

```
p(a, X, Y) :- p(b, X, Y, Z), p(a, Y, Z).
```

using the same universal predicate `p` throughout?

This translation would allow us to quantify over what used to be predicates (`a` and `b`), while staying in the original first-order Datalog.

Can you give an example of what higher-order Datalog can express that first-order Datalog with the above translation scheme cannot?

---

[1] Non-paywalled link: https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.09820

Comment: Stab in the dark: is [this](https://billwadge.com/2016/01/18/extensional-higher-order-prolog/) relevant in any way?